# make_pair(string, class): error: expected primary-expression before â)â token

Tags: c++, dictionary

> error: expected primary-expression before â)â token

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, since my friends also working on this project can't seem to tell what's wrong. Any help on this error would be appreciated. The line that the error is referring to has a comment on it pointing it out. I'm trying to insert a pair into a map by the code below.

`theCandidates` is a `map<string, class>`, and in this case, that class is called Candidate.

```
void TallyVotes::initialize(Scanner& inStream)
    {   
        numberOfLosers = 0;
        numberOfVotes = boost::lexical_cast<int>(inStream.next());
        numberOfCandidates = boost::lexical_cast<int>(inStream.next());
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVotes ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < numberOfCandidates ; i++)
            {
                theVotes[i][j] = inStream.next();
                cand = theVotes[i][j];
                if(i == 0)
                {   
                    theCandidates.insert(make_pair(cand, Candidate));//ERROR ON THIS LINE       
                }
            }
        }
    } // void TallyVotes::initialize(Scanner& inStream)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) function takes two *values* as arguments, not a value and a *type*.

Try e.g.

```
make_pair(cand, Candidate())
//      Note parentheses ^^
```

The expression `Candidate()` create a temporary object, which is then copied into the `std::map`.

Comment: Alternatively, replace the whole line with `theCandidates[cand];`